# Choosing 1x2 Connector for PCB

Tags: power-supply, pcb-design, connector

On my pcb I need a 2-pin female wire-to-board connector on which 120V DC will arrive.

What is the standard way to approach this? (I got [this one](https://www.digikey.it/en/products/detail/molex/0395237002/2737953) for example)

Thanks!

Comment: Asking for product recommendations is generally off-topic as the products can change and the answer will not change. Then people in the future will find the question with out-dated recommendations

Comment: It's not a part recommendation, but IMHO a question about a connector *type*. What current does it carry?

Comment: You need to specify in great detail what you actually need for a question like this to be acceptable. Board to board, board to wire? If wire what AWG? Clearance/creepage/isolation requirements? Why female? Current requirements? Indoors/outdoors? Temperatures? Preferred soldering method, SMD or through-hole? And so on...

Comment: @user253751
 As I read it, OP is not asking for a product recommendation, but for the standard  solution to bringing high voltage power to a board.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use a female connector for a power inlet: the male plug for it is unsafe.

Instead, use a female plug on the power cord and a male inlet on your board.

Any wire-to-board connector with a pitch of greater than 2.54 mm will work. A standard solution is a [3.96 mm pitch, single-wall, wire-to-board connector](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=single_wall_w2b_conn_3p96). (My site.)

The volatge rating can be increased by skipping the middle pin (as shown in this picture). The plug in this picture is latched, though unlatched plugs are more common.

[image: Single wall connector collage]

You can buy the [male PCB header here](https://www.digikey.com/short/q89tpnd2) and the [female plug housing here](https://www.digikey.com/short/b0tz25j0).

Comment: Thank you!

On Digi Key I searched for 'wire to board' and filtered for both pitch>2.54mm and molex.
But I can't find male/female (contact type) in the filters

I attach a link to the research:    https://www.digikey.com/short/jq81dvdd

Comment: Probably because I looked for Terminal Blocks Categories.

In this category there are 'Headers, Plugs and Sockets' (the green ones) ... would that be OK for this application?

Comment: Not only it is OK, it is the preferred solution in the industry.